# Storm door panel replacement?

Tags: storm-door

Basically someone kicked the bottom of my storm door, denting the panel there. It looks like I should just be able to replace it but I can't find a new panel anywhere. Not sure if there's a special name for it or something so here's a picture to be clear what I'm talking about:

[image]

So does anyone know what the name of that part is and/or where I could buy it?

Answer (score 1):

A shop that fabricates sheet metal can probably fabricate a new one. A company that installs metal roof systems would be a good candidate because they deal with pre-finished materials on a regular basis. An HVAC shop could probably also fabricate something but they are less likely to have a finished material.

If you're ambitious, you could perhaps fabricate something yourself out of sheet metal.

Comment: Fabricating a new piece would be ideal, however you'd still need to attach it the same way you'd just repair this one; file-off the new, protruding tips of 1/4" sheet metal screws, or something else akin to how it attached originally. -Remove it, bang the dents out and put it back.

Answer (score 0):

The panel is manufacturer specific, and you may not be able to get a replacement panel. Depending on the construction of the door, you may be able to remove the bottom style of the door and slide out the panel. If you're lucky, the bottom is just held in with screws. If you can get the panel out, you may be able to straighten it and slide it back in. Then you can put the door back together and rehang it.